# help in php file_get_contents

Tags: php, fpdf

i have this file `C:\\xampp\htdocs\exact\sample_pie.php` that contains a graph. here's the code:

```
<?php
include("phpgraphlib.php");
include("phpgraphlib_pie.php");
include("connection.php");
$graph=new PHPGraphLibPie(400,200); 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('exact');

$querypa = "SELECT COUNT(nature) FROM approved WHERE nature='Parade'";
$resultpa = mysql_query($querypa);
$printpa = mysql_result($resultpa,0);
$querycs = "SELECT COUNT(nature) FROM approved WHERE nature='Community Service'";
$resultcs = mysql_query($querycs);
$printcs = mysql_result($resultcs,0);
$queryga = "SELECT COUNT(nature) FROM approved WHERE nature='General Assembly'";
$resultga = mysql_query($queryga);
$printga = mysql_result($resultga,0);
$querypl = "SELECT COUNT(nature) FROM approved WHERE nature='Play/Showcase/Socio-Cultural Show/Film Showing'";
$resultpl = mysql_query($querypl);
$printpl = mysql_result($resultpl,0);
$queryco = "SELECT COUNT(nature) FROM approved WHERE nature='Competition/Sportsfest'";
$resultco = mysql_query($queryco);
$printco = mysql_result($resultco,0);
$queryfr = "SELECT COUNT(nature) FROM approved WHERE nature='Fund Raising'";
$resultfr = mysql_query($queryfr);
$printfr = mysql_result($resultfr,0);
$queryse = "SELECT COUNT(nature) FROM approved WHERE nature='Seminar/Convention/Conference/Training'";
$resultse = mysql_query($queryse);
$printse = mysql_result($resultse,0);


$totalAct=$printpa+$printga+$printpl+$printcs+$printco+$printfr+$printse;
$avepa=($printpa/$totalAct)*100;
$avecs=($printcs/$totalAct)*100;
$avega=($printga/$totalAct)*100;
$avepl=($printpl/$totalAct)*100;
$aveco=($printco/$totalAct)*100;
$avefr=($printfr/$totalAct)*100;
$avese=($printse/$totalAct)*100;
$pa=number_format($avepa,2);
$cs=number_format($avecs,2);
$ga=number_format($avega,2);
$pl=number_format($avepl,2);
$co=number_format($aveco,2);
$fr=number_format($avefr,2);
$se=number_format($avese,2);

$data=array("Parade"=>$pa, "General Assembly"=>$ga, "Play/Showcase/Socio-Cultural Show/Film Showing"=>$pl, "Community Service"=>$cs, "Competition/Sportsfest"=>$co, "Fund Raising"=>$fr, "Seminar/Convention/Conference/Training"=>$se);
$graph->addData($data);
$graph->setTitle("Total Activities per Nature of Activity");
$graph->setPrecision(2);
$graph->setLabelTextColor("0,0,0");
$graph->setLegendTextColor("0,0,0");
$graph->setGradient("210,245,255","pastel_purple");

$graph->createGraph();

?>
```

how can i get the graph as a .jpg through php script? i tried this `file_get_contents("C:\\xampp\htdocs\exact\sample_pie.php");`
but it only outputs this:

```
$pa, "General Assembly"=>$ga, "Play/Showcase/Socio-Cultural Show/Film Showing"=>$pl, "Community Service"=>$cs, "Competition/Sportsfest"=>$co, "Fund Raising"=>$fr, "Seminar/Convention/Conference/Training"=>$se); $graph->addData($data); $graph->setTitle("Total Activities per Nature of Activity"); $graph->setPrecision(2); $graph->setLabelTextColor("0,0,0"); $graph->setLegendTextColor("0,0,0"); $graph->setGradient("210,245,255","pastel_purple"); $graph->createGraph(); ?>
```

please help me. thanks.

Comment: The library you're using outputs the graph into GIF format, it appears.

Why do you need the output of the image?

Comment: i need to put the image in a pdf file which is an annual report. the image is a chart.

Comment: Can't you just save it from your browser?

Answer (score 1):

Using `file_get_contents()` like that is only going to retrieve the script itself. That text is what the file contains and that's what `file_get_contents()` does; exactly what it says on the tin.

Try looking at the documentation for PHPGraphLib or in the source code failing that. There should be some sort of save method you can call instead of `createGraph()` or maybe you can just pass a filename parameter to `createGraph()`.

Answer (score 1):

On a sidenote, I should mention that your script is a lot more complicated than it should be. Everything between `mysql_select_db()` and `$graph->addData()` could be rewritten into something like this:

```
$data = array(
    'Parade' => 0,
    'Community Service' => 0,
    'General Assembly' => 0,
    'Play/Showcase/Socio-Cultural Show/Film Showing' => 0,
    'Competition/Sportsfest' => 0,
    'Fund Raising' => 0,
    'Seminar/Convention/Conference/Training' => 0
);

$sql = "SELECT nature, COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM approved
         WHERE nature IN ('" . implode("','", array_keys($data)) . "')
      GROUP BY nature";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $data[$row['nature']] = $row['cnt'];
}
$totalAct = array_sum($data);

foreach ($data as $nature => &$value)
{
    $value = number_format(100 * $value / $totalAct, 2);
}
```

For the rest, consult the documentation of your graph library as Ollie Saunders suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="/exact/sample_pie.php" />
```

You may want to use `header()` to set the appropriate Content-type from within sample_pie.php.